# Android - How to call all items in an array

Tags: android, arrays

I got a simple question for you I can't seem to figure out. I have an array of buttons `Button[] buttons =  new Button[9];` and obviously this is going to include nine buttons. Is there anyway to call all of them? Instead of calling them each individually

```
buttons[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b0);
buttons[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
buttons[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
buttons[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
...
```

like so, is there anyway I can go about something like

```
int all[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
buttons[all] = DOCODEHERE;
```

Comment: Try a foreach loop, for(Button b in buttons)...

Comment: Alright thanks, I will get back with you soon whether or not this works. Of course my developing device died and takes a lifetime to charge.